# Issues with installing NPM mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

I'm taking an intro class to Mean.  I installed MongoDB and mongoose but I don't think I installed them right in the same folder..as I'm learning.  When I try to run:  node `nodemongoose.js` I get this error: the `nodemongoose.js` is a file for the class...it is in the folder I am in for the Terminal window)

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dave/Documents/Software/mongoose/nodeapi.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
```

I tried installing using `npm install mongoose` and then I get this error: `npm WARN install Refusing to install mongoose as a dependency of itself`

Any suggestions?  Do I need to uninstall and re-install?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove mongoose, reinstall locally:

1. `npm uninstall mongoose` run twice, to make sure any local and global installations are removed.
2. `npm install mongoose` (do *not* use -g flag!) in your project root, from an elevated CMD.

Note the installation process, and make sure no errors come up. If anything shows that looks odd, please go ahead and add the log to your question.

Note that the warning you get regarding dependency is related to you trying to install mongoose while you are in mongoose directory. You should `npm i mongoose` in *your project* directory.

Comment: Nitai. Thanks very much. Your advice worked!  I'm all set now.

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall mongooose

up to date, audited 96 packages in 1s

12 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

4 vulnerabilities (3 high, 1 critical)

a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS D:\work\Mern Stack\Mangodb> npm install mongoose

up to date, audited 96 packages in 1s

12 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

4 vulnerabilities (3 high, 1 critical)

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS D:\work\Mern Stack\Mangodb> npm audit

## npm audit report

bson  <=1.1.3
Severity: critical
Deserialization of Untrusted Data in bson - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4jwp-vfvf-657p
Deserialization of Untrusted Data in bson - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-v8w9-2789-6hhr
No fix available
node_modules/mongos/node_modules/bson
mongodb  <=3.1.12
Depends on vulnerable versions of bson
Depends on vulnerable versions of kerberos
node_modules/mongos/node_modules/mongodb
mongos  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of mongodb
node_modules/mongos

kerberos  <1.0.0
Severity: high
DLL Injection in kerberos - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-m2mx-rfpw-jghv
No fix available
node_modules/kerberos

4 vulnerabilities (3 high, 1 critical)

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34412726)